# Is it possible to change width a row in Grafana?

Tags: grafana

I wanna change width a **row** in Grafana v5.4.0.
like this [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2t8P.png) ...

I'm trying to change JSON Model...

```
"collapsed": false,
  "gridPos": {
    "h": 1,
    "w": 18,
    "x": 0,
    "y": 14
  },
  "id": 12,
  "panels": [],
  "title": "row2",
  "type": "row"
```

I modified 'w'value from 24 to 18.

'Save changes' is  is Succeed.
But, Actually not changed.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately the row size cannot be changed. Rows are always 12 units wide. 
Check these docs: https://docs.huihoo.com/grafana/2.6/guides/basic_concepts/index.html